# ng serve hangs at 15% of building modules

Tags: angular, angular-cli

#### OS?

os: win32 x64

#### Versions.

angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.24
/ node: 7.3.0

#### Repro steps.

New app created by angular-cli. Didn't done any changes.

#### The log given by the failure.

** NG Live Development Server is running on http://localhost:4200. **
 15% building modules 46/148 modules 102 active ...core-js\modules\es6.array.index-of.js

I have downgrade the Nodejs to version 6.9.2 and reinstalled angular-cli.

But it gives same error. I guess error coming from core-js@2.4.1. But I don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

There are intermittent incidents of this reported to the main github repo. None of them is happening all the time. If that was a customized repository I'd ask you to push repository of a generated project that has the problem reproducible and create a new issue with it.

But since you say it's just new project, it might be an earlier version of the CLI that is not cleaned well. In that case, let's try:

```
npm uninstall --global angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install --global angular-cli
ng new sample-project
cd sample-project
ng build
```

If you used Yarn instead of NPM to install it, please uninstall it from Yarn as well at first (otherwise, just ignore this bit).

**Update:**

Now I remember one thing. You are using Node 7. This might be the problem. Some of the popular sub-dependencies of the CLI used to show warning that they fail with Node 7.

You might need to try installing the latest LTS Node (LTS = Long Term Support), which is currently Node 6.x, and try again.

I can see the `project.json` setting does not reject Node 7 though, so, this one might be a miss. Only try it if the step before the update fails.

Comment: Hi @Meligy, I have downgrade the Nodejs to version 6.9.2 and reinstalled angular-cli. But it gives same error. I guess error coming from core-js@2.4.1. But I don't know how to solve this.